# combinations of each string of a column with each string of another column in R

Tags: r

This is the table with many rows, but for simplicity of the problem...

```
dt1 <-data.frame(col1=c("C,Y,M","B,C,M,A"),col2=c("B,E,M","B,A,G"),col3=c("2","10"))

     col1          col2         col3
1    C,Y,M         B,E,M        2
2    B,C,M,A       B,F,G        10
```

So what I am trying to do is

**1.** every string of each column should be paired, but if there is a common string ignore that, for example C with B, C with E but not C with M because M is there in both the columns of that row and similarly Y with B, Y with E again not with M.

**2.** Their corresponding values as col3

the output table

```
dt2 <- data.frame(col1 =c("C","C","Y","Y","C","C","M","M","A","A"),col2 = c("B","E","B","E","F","G","F","G","F","G"),col3=c("2","2","2","2","10","10","10","10","10","10"))

  col1      col2       col3
1    C         B          2  
2    C         E          2
3    Y         B          2
4    Y         E          2
5    C         F         10
6    C         G         10
7    M         F         10
8    M         G         10
9    A         F         10
10   A         G         10
```

Comment: Please try to break down your question in smaller pieces. Do you know how to split a string? Do you know how to make combinations two vectors of strings? Do you know how to exclude cases where the strings are identical? Etc, etc, etc. Please show us where _your current code_ (yes, we assume you have tried something) fail.

Comment: Try `cSplit(cSplit(dt1, 1, ",", "long") , 2, ",", "long")`

Comment: @Henrik, Yes I have tried using strsplit and expand.grid functions, but having trouble in excluding the cases where strings are identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try something like this (note that there's a mistake in your sample data....):

```
dt1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("C,Y,M","B,C,M,A"), 
                  col2 = c("B,E,M","B,F,G"), 
                  col3 = c("2","10"))

x <- lapply(dt1, function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ",", TRUE))

myFun <- function(x, y, z) {
  drop <- intersect(x, y)
  expand.grid(x[!x %in% drop], y[!y %in% drop], z)
}

do.call(rbind, Map(myFun, x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]))
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1     C    B    2
# 2     Y    B    2
# 3     C    E    2
# 4     Y    E    2
# 5     C    F   10
# 6     M    F   10
# 7     A    F   10
# 8     C    G   10
# 9     M    G   10
# 10    A    G   10
```